# Implementing 3DSecure in InAppBrowser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm currently writing an app which use 3DS (3DSecure) but I can't make it work on my mobile device (currently testing on Android).

When I get the Bank URL, I window.open this, post in it, it redirects to the 3DSecured web page, I can authenticate, but I just can't close the inAppBrowser at the end of the process.

Here is the popup the user clicks :

```
function showPopup3ds($ionicPopup, $scope, $window) {
    var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
        title: 'Paiement sécurisé',
        subTitle: 'Confirmez votre transaction grâce au 3D Secure fourni par votre établissement bancaire.',
        scope: $scope,
        buttons: [{
            text: '<b>Continuer</b>',
            type: 'button-positive',
            onTap: function(e) {
                // creating the 'formresult' window with custom features prior to submitting the form
                ref = $window.open($scope.p3ds.threeDSEncodedPareq, 'formresult', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0');

                // <form id="redirectForm" name="redirectForm" target="formresult" action="{{p3ds.threeDSAcsUrl | trusted }}" method="POST" class="hide"> 
                document.forms['redirectForm'].submit();
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }]
    });
}
```

And then, juste after :

```
showPopup3ds($ionicPopup, $scope, $window);
socket.on(result.veResPAReqInfo.threeDSRequestId, function(data) {
    console.log(ref);
    ref.close();
    showPopupResult($ionicPopup, $scope, data.success);
})
```

But I can't close it, or listen to any event because de page is redirected. It's not like a new tab or new window, it's a redirection.

I feel a bit desperate, I wish I could open a chrome tab or any other.

Wish you can help me.

Kai23

Edit: here is how I did :

In my view ( payment_details.html ), I have the current form :

```
<form id="redirectForm" name="redirectForm" target="hidden_iframe" action="{{p3ds.threeDSAcsUrl | trusted }}" method="POST" class="hide"> 
    <input type="hidden" id="PaReq" name="PaReq" value="{{p3ds.threeDSEncodedPareq}}"> 
    <input type="hidden" id="TermUrl" name="TermUrl" value="{{p3ds.TermUrl}}"> 
    <input type="hidden" id="MD" name="MD" value="{{p3ds.MD}}"> 
</form>
```

And I have an ionic modal view like this one :

```
<ion-modal-view>
    <ion-header-bar>
        <h1 class="title">Paiement sécurisé 3-D Secure</h1>
        <button class="button button-dark" ng-click="hide_modal(modal)">Fermer</button>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content  scroll="true" overflow-scroll="true" class="has-header padding">
        <iframe name="hidden_iframe" style="width:100%;height:100%"></iframe>
    </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

Finally, in my PaymentController, I do something like this :

```
$scope.p3ds.threeDSAcsUrl = result.
$scope.p3ds.threeDSEncodedPareq = result.
$scope.p3ds.TermUrl = api_url + '/retour-banque?token=' + $window.sessionStorage['
$scope.p3ds.MD = result.id;

var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
    title: 'Paiement sécurisé',
    subTitle: 'Confirmez votre transaction grâce au 3D Secure fourni par votre établissement bancaire.',
    scope: $scope,
    buttons: [{
        text: '<b>Continuer</b>',
        type: 'button-positive',
        onTap: function(e) {
            $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/payment/popup/modal_3DS.html', {
                scope: $scope,
                animation: 'slide-in-up'
            }).then(function(modal) {
                $scope.modal = modal;
                $scope.modal.show();
                document.forms['redirectForm'].submit();
            });
        }
    }]
});
```

Server side, here is how it looks like (I use nodejs, and cheated a lot)

```
// Once the transaction is complete
res.ok("<p>Votre transaction a bien été enregistrée ! Revenez sur votre compte Payname en cliquant sur « fermer »");

// English : res.ok("<p>Transaction succeeded. Come back to your Payname account using the close button");
```

Which would be, in PHP

```
die("...")
```

Hope it helps,